# persisting data of webservice response to forward to websocket

Tags: java, node.js, web-services, jsp, websocket

I am trying to fetch data through webservice and forward it to the browser through websocketing. So that, I can validate the response of webservice based on the individual websocket opened connection.

Basically, it would be

**SERVER1** ---->**WEBSERVICE CALL** ----> **SERVER TO VALIDATE DATA** <====> *open from client* <----**WEBSOCKET**----> *listens to IP through* <====>**CLIENT**

The client is opening a connection to start listening for a particular data for a given MAC address.

I am facing a problem to bypass the data received from webservices to the listener port and IP.

So that, I am trying to persist it using JPA (ODB) objectDB, we could able to store into .odb, but whereas, when trying to make a request to fetch .odb from another application server(CLIENT) to the validator server(SERVER TO VALIDATE DATA). I am getting nothing.

I feel that might be because of lack of session handler among different ***webapps***.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/echo")         //websocket
@Path("/json/metallica")         //webservice
public class JSONService {

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

        // where I am storing into db---------**** step
    }

    // connection OPENED from differnet **webapp**
    @OnMessage
    public void echoTextMessage(Session session, String msg, boolean last) {
        if (session.isOpen()) {
        //I couldn't able to fetch the data from db which I stored in ---------**** step.
    }
}
```

I am getting empty results. Any suggestions where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you implement SSO?

Comment: Hi, Presently SSO is not part of it. It is seperately maintained out of this usecase.

Comment: How do you make request?

Comment: Request is sent to SERVER TO VALIDATE DATA through ws://<host>:<port>/......